# Permanently hide or move taskbar off screen windows 10 LTSB ENT

Tags: c#, windows, dllimport

We need to hide the taskbar and start menu. We have an app that runs full screen, it is a touch screen application. Our touch screen application is 99.9999% always on screen, covering the entire screen. It is however a complex multimedia app and on rare occasions we have found it crashed exposing the desktop. We have a custom made Win10 LTSB ENT build which is robust and appropriate, but we want to go a step further. We want to remove the taskbar (which is 'hidden') from the desktop entirely.

We can hide the taskbar using the code below, but it keeps returning 5 seconds later. Something keeps undoing our 'hide' and restoring the taskbar without us doing anything.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a service or mechanism in Windows OS I need to adjust?

```
private static void setTaskBar(bool hide)
{
  IntPtr window = Program.FindWindow("Shell_traywnd", "");
  if (hide)
    Program.SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128U);
  else
    Program.SetWindowPos(window, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64U);

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(
  IntPtr hWndl,
  IntPtr hWnd2,
  string lpsz1,
  string lpsz2);
}

[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(
  IntPtr hWndl,
  IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
  int X,
  int Y,
  int cx,
  int cy,
  uint uFlags);
```

Comment: Have you considered running you app in [Kiosk Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/kiosk-single-app) ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson we have 100's of existing deployments - in the future maybe but adjusting the OS in the field to enable Kiosk mode isn't ideal.

Comment: You can do Kiosk mode yourself by setting the default shell, see https://realtimeissues.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/how-to-change-default-shell-of-windows-or-how-to-set-one-program-as-windows-shell-program/

Comment: @Charlieface unfortunately we have many applications which support the main application. they launch independently and service various aspects over the overall function available from the touch app. I'm not sure Kiosk, or replacing the shell is the right path for us today.

Comment: Moving around a window that doesn't belong to you is definitely not the right way. " Is there a service or mechanism in Windows OS I need to adjust?" Yes, use Kiosk mode, or Shell Launcher, or change the shell manually. Otherwise Explorer desktop will always be there running in the background, ready to pop out when your app crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The taskbar is somewhat special, it receives messages from the window manager when other windows go in and out of fullscreen etc and adjusts itself accordingly.

Messing with the shell is the wrong solution. A better solution would be to launch another instance of your program that only has a fullscreen window and does nothing but waiting for the real instance to crash and then restart it if desired.

Comment: Thanks, we do have a watchdog which monitors and relaunches. I'm just trying to account for the 00001% of times something really goes wrong. however.. the watchdog itself isn't full screen... we might look into this.